# Telescoping Series: If only $\liminf$ does exist, and not $\lim$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Consider the following telescoping series:

$$S:=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} (x_t - x_{t+1}).$$

If $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} x_t=0,$$ then this simplifies to

$$S=x_0 - \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} x_t=x_0.$$

However, if the limit does not exist, but under the assumption that $$\liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} x_t = 0,$$ we want to show that

$$S \geq x_0.$$

Can you help me with this? (I have not studied maths). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove it, because it is not true. Consider $x_t=0$ if $t$ is odd and $x_t = 1$ if $t$ is even. Then 
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} (x_t - x_{t+1})$$ 
does not converge, because 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{t=0}^{n} (x_t - x_{t+1})$$ 
does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for this counterexample. Could you tell me which conditions would be enough in order to prove this? In fact, I am interested in proving this for $x_t:=\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ the expectation of non-negative random variables $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ over a finite state space. Moreover $\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_{t+1} \mid X_t >0]\geq c$ for some constant $c$. Does this help to prove the statement?

Comment: Of course I mean $\leq c$ and not $\geq c$. So intuitively it should be somehow clear. We decrease in expectation in every step and only have finitely many possible values.

Comment: First you completely changed the topic of your question, so I suggest that you create new question. But few comments before you do it:

1.The conditional expectation  $\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_{t+1} \mid X_t >0]$ is a random variable not a constant so I assume you're inequality should hold almost sure?
  
2.You said nothing about relations between $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$, are they i.i.d.?

3.Beware of intuition! I afraid it drives you the wrong path and be sure that you understand all notation you are using.

Comment: Your "new theorem" is not a properly defined but if I understand it correctly I have counterexample. Define $X_t ~\sim \text{Unif}([-1,1])$ for $t$ even and $X_t ~\sim \text{Unif}([1,2])$ for $t$ odd and assume, that all are independent. You can check that all conditions are satisfied ($\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_{t+1} \mid X_t >0] < 2$ a.s.) but the sum of mean $EX_t$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you again for trying to help me. I really appreciate this! And sorry if things are stated unclear, I try to express it as clear as I can. So first of all, your counterexample would be excluded, since I have non-negative random variables, so $Unif([-1,1])$ is not allowed. Then $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ can be arbitrarily dependent and need not follow the same distribution. All we know about them is that $\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_{t+1} \mid X_t > 0]\leq c$ a.s.

Comment: I tried to post a new question with your suggested changes here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173630/telescoping-sum-of-expectations-limsup
Thank you very much for your help. If you would like to help me with the new question, I would really appreciate this! Anyway: you seem to have answered the question I have asked here, so I will accept your answer. Thank you!