# Telescoping Sum of expectations: limsup exists but limes not necessarily

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, expectation, limsup-and-liminf, conditional-expectation

Let $X_t$ for $t \in \{0, 1, \dotsc, \}$ be a sequence of  **non-negative integer-valued** random variables. Suppose that $$\mathbb{E}[X_t - X_{t+1} \mid X_t>0 ] \leq c \quad \text{  for some constant }  c \text{, for all } t \geq 0$$
and for all possible outcomes $\omega \in \Omega$.

Moreover assume that

$$\liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_t] = 0.$$

Can we show that

$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \left(\mathbb{E}[X_t]- \mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}]\right)\geq \mathbb{E}[X_0]?$$

**Concrete Example**: Random Declines. 
Let $X_0=n$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence we have a deterministic starting value. Then choose $X_{t+1}$ uniformly at random from the set $\{0, \dotsc, \lfloor e X_t \rfloor\}$ for all $t \geq 0$. Can we say that $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} (\mathbb{E}[X_t]-\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}])\geq \mathbb{E}[X_0]= n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the sequence of independent random variables $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ where
\begin{align}
X_t & \sim Unif((1,2)) &~\text{if}~& t=2k \\
X_t & \sim Unif((0,\frac{1}{t})) &~\text{if}~& t=2k + 1 
\end{align}
for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then your sum does not converge.

If you want to prove that sum 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$ 
converge (so you can define something using it) you have to know (prove) that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0.$$
Otherwise the sum is not defined.

**Edit**:
Since OP put another assumption I have to create another counterexample: think about the sequence of independent random variables $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$  such that 
\begin{align}
X_t & \sim Y &~\text{if}~& t=2k \\
X_t & \sim \frac{1}{t}.Y &~\text{if}~& t=2k + 1 
\end{align}
where $Y$ has Bernouli distribution with $p=0.5$ Again your sum does not converge.

**Existence of limit of $a_n$**:

If 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = \lim_{k \to \infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n $$ 
exists, than for all $m >1$ 
$$|a_m| \leq \left| \sum_{n=1}^{m}a_n - \sum_{n=1}^{m-1}a_n \right|. $$
Since you assume that the infinite sum converge, the right hand side of the previous inequality goes to $0$ as $m \to \infty$. So the 
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} |a_m| = 0.$$

**Edit 2:**

Counterexample no. 3: define sequence of independent random variables $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that every $X_t$ has Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p_t$. Define these parameters as follows
\begin{align}
p_t &=\frac{1}{2} &~\text{if}~& t=2k, \\
p_t &= \frac{1}{t} &~\text{if}~& t=2k + 1. 
\end{align}
Again the desired sum does not converge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I am afraid my task here is exactly to show that even though $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \neq 0$, but with $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$, that we can work with it by just taking the first summand. So as I still seem to oversee some of the assumptions: Could you tell me under which assumptions (instead of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n=0$) my statement above holds?

Comment: oh of course, I forgot to mention that, I am sorry: I want $X_t$ to be non-negative INTEGER-VALUED random variables, so your example still would not work as counterexample. Sorry, I have an application example and try to read off all the important properties of the random variables. And I am quite a beginner, so I always miss something important. I apologize for that!

Comment: If $lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq  0$ then the sum does not converge! I edited my answer and prove it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your edits. I still do not get why your second counterexample should be integervalued, can't $\frac{Y}{t}$ be an arbitrary rational number?
But besides of that: I looked through your proof and I must say that I am no mathematician (as you may have noticed) and I am not sure whether and under what circumstances the order of the sum and the limit can be interchanged, so I am not really sure whether I could apply it for my setting or not. Maybe it's time to mention the concrete example, as I need to prove it for this.

Comment: Ok, there si counterexample no. 3. In the proof I did not change the order of sum and limit, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n := \lim_{k \to \infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n$ is a definition. I encourage you to ask another question with the problem you really have, but before it please read at least something about [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29) and especially about [convergent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Convergent_series) and maybe also reading about [Grandi series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series) could be beneficial.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this one sentence. It is clear to me that this is a definition, I thought you were talking about something different. I think the answer is not so much in theory of series but much more applied (since I am an engineer and not mathematician and it is an exercise presented to us), but I will try to think about it again. Sorry for bothering you again and again and thanks for your patience.

Comment: I don't know exact rules of this website but maybe putting your example as a individual question is a not a bad idea. Since this addition changed the question a lot. But be aware that your sum is a **random variable**.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I do not know the rules either, but I will open another question concerning the concrete example. 

But I still do not see why my sum should be a random variable. I mean, I do not sum over conditional expectations but over expectations. Every expectation is a fixed number and we sum them up. I cannot see why this should be a random variable.

Comment: Yes you are right, the sum is not a random variable, sorry mea culpa:-). Please if you open new question say how you get the inequality $\mathbb{E}[X_t - X_{t+1} \mid X_t>0 ] \leq c$ as right now I wouldn't bet that you example satisfies it (on the other hand I neither would bet on the opposite).